# How to show ajax data into while loop?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, while-loop

I have fetched some car brand names in a while loop and then for each brand name I make a select menu for the car names in another while loop by using the "brand id" as foreign key. And then I want to show the car names in a box each time someone changes the dropdown select options. Here's my code below :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM brands";
$result = $db->query($query);

// Outer while loop
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $brand_id = $row->id;
    ?>

    <div id="result"></div>  <!-- The Ajax result will be shown here -->

    <div><?php echo $row->brand_name ?></div>
    <?php

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand_id = ?";
    $result2 = $db->prepare($query);
    $result2->execute(array($brand_id));

    <select name="car" id="car">
       // Inner while loop
       while($row2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row2->id ?>"><?php echo $row2->car_name ?></option>
          <?php
        }  // Closing Inner while loop
    ?>
    </select>

        <!-- Ajax -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#car').change(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var car = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {car: car},
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
     <?php
      }  // Closing outer while loop
```

In the ajax.php I have written the following code to echo the car name

```
$carName = $_POST['car'];
echo $carName;
```

But the issue is - it is just executed for the first option selected inside first inner loop of the first outer loop. I mean the ajax code only runs for the first iteration of the both loops.

I also tried to make the select menu and the result div unique by adding the "brand id" as follow :

```
<div id="result<?php echo $brand_id ?>"></div>
```

and

```
<select name="car" id="car<?php echo $brand_id ?>">
    <option value="<?php echo $row2->id ?>"><?php echo $row2->car_name ?></option>
</select>
```

and also the ajax as following :

```
       $('#car<?php echo $brand_id ?>').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var car = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {car: car},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#result<?php echo $brand_id ?>').html(data);
                }
        });
```

But it didn't work. Please suggest your best possible solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console? Adding text to the ID's is definitely the way to go (you can't have two elements on the page which have the same ID)

Comment: Should the URL be `ajax.php` rather than `ajax`? Just something you could try

Comment: No there's no js errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` and ajax code should be out of while loop. just check the code below

```
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM brands";
$result = $db->query($query);

// Outer while loop
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $brand_id = $row->id;
    ?>

    <div id="result"></div>  <!-- The Ajax result will be shown here -->

    <div><?php echo $row->brand_name ?></div>
    <?php

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand_id = ?";
    $result2 = $db->prepare($query);
    $result2->execute(array($brand_id)); ?>

    <select name="car" id="car">

        <?
       // Inner while loop
       while($row2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row2->id ?>"><?php echo $row2->car_name ?></option>
          <?php
        }  // Closing Inner while loop
    ?>
    </select>

        <!-- Ajax -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#car').change(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var car = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {car: car},
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
     <?php
      }  // Closing outer while loop

      ?>


``
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM brands";
$result = $db->query($query);

// Outer while loop
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $brand_id = $row->id;
    ?>

    <div id="result<?php echo $brand_id;?>"></div>  <!-- The Ajax result will be shown here -->

    <div><?php echo $row->brand_name ?></div>
    <?php

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand_id = ?";
    $result2 = $db->prepare($query);
    $result2->execute(array($brand_id));

    // Inner while loop
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        ?>
        <select name="car[]" id="car<?php echo $row2->id ?>">
            <option value="<?php echo $row2->id ?>"><?php echo     $row2->car_name ?></option>
        </select>

        <!-- Ajax -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#car<?php echo $row2->id ?>').change(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var car = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {car: car},
                        success: function(data){
console.log(data);
                            $('#result<?php echo $brand_id;?>').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>

        <?php
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not call ajax() in a while loop.
Simply you can call **`.change()`** on

```
<select name="car" onchange="getCar(this.value)"> 



<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCar(car) {            
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {car: car},
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html('');
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>


<div id="result"></div>
```